# HttpClient object Timeout property vs DefaultRequestHeaders Keep-alive

Tags: asp.net-web-api, dotnet-httpclient

Could you please let me know the difference between HttpClient object Timeout property vs the DefaultRequestHeaders "Keep-Alive".

httpClient.Timeout = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(10);

vs

httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Connection", "Keep-Alive");
httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Keep-Alive", "600");

Answer (score 1):

The timeout is the time the client will wait for a response. Keep-alive is for reusing an already opened TCP connection for subsequent HTTP requests.